# how to select several columns based on grep?

Tags: r

Given a data frame `data`

```
     data <- data.frame(col1 = 1:5,                      # 
      Create example data
               famg = letters[1:5],
               xxm = letters[5:1],
               x2 = 5:1)
              data
```

I want to keep the columns that containe

```
     tokeep=c("col","xm","fa")
```

I used

```
   data[grep(tokeep, names(data))]
```

please note that tokeep  is long than this example so i do not want to just use  "col"|"xm"|"fa" but rather  tokeep

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you can try

```
data[grep(paste0(tokeep,collapse = "|"),names(data))]
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this work:

```
data[grep(paste(tokeep, collapse = '|'), colnames(data))]
  col1 famg xxm
1    1    a   e
2    2    b   d
3    3    c   c
4    4    d   b
5    5    e   a
```

Answer (score 1):

alternative way with `dplyr` package

```
data %>% select(contains(tokeep))
  col1 xxm famg
1    1   e    a
2    2   d    b
3    3   c    c
4    4   b    d
5    5   a    e
```

Comment: FYI `print` is often not needed in R. Nice answer +1

Comment: @Maël You're right. Sorry, I use vscode :((  I edit my answer.

Comment: No worries! it takes time to learn the subtleties of a language